# 0 getting inserted into table fields

Tags: codeigniter

I have a website done using code igniter. My issue is in the registration form where '0' values getting inserted into my database  table columns without any known submission. i can view the IP address from  which the registrations comes. Since java script validations are given, also one field is readonly in my form, am surprised how '0' get dumped into my table fields. This dummy registration happen 2 or 3 at a time, then after few hours may be another insertion. can someone help to deal with it.

Comment: Did you added server side validations using CI?

Comment: how are you inserting into database. Can you show?

Comment: Iam adding values using ajax. Getting the values from the form usina ajax post to controller and then inserting from model. Its javascript validation,not server side.

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: You should always have javascript validation backed up by server side validation. All it takes is for someone to turn off JS in their browser, and your validation is bypassed.

Comment: javascript validation is not enough, therefor you still need `serverside` validation.
please post your code so we can tell you what to do.
post javascript part and the php one also.

Comment: suggest a good server side validation for me.

Comment: $.ajax({
      
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>signup/reg_form",
                        data: "ct="+cat+"&cname="+comp_name+"&cperson="+cont_person+"&ab="+abn+"&address="+address+"&suburb="+suburb+"&postal="+postal+"&state="+state+"&country="+country+"&phone="+phone+"&mobile="+mobile+"&email="+email+"&website="+website+"&comments="+comments+"&type=log",
         success: function(data)
                        {}

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented same functionality in which required ajax call to save data.

I suggest to implement server side validation for the ajax call and check the value of form posted then validate  and insert only entry with valid value or not null.

Comment: suggest any link to refer?

Comment: But its not public link its client website and i have implemented in admin side. Please show your code so i can help further.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely the way you are sending your data from AJAX. The most accurate way that works for me is the following:

```
    var url = "http://...";
    var dataToSend= {'company':company, 'dateFrom':dateFrom, .....};
    $.post(url, dataToSend, function(data) {

       alert(data);

    });
```

Comment: some is trying to input the value 0 through url or something.coz same 0 value get inserted twice at a time from a same IP.then other two insertion with another Ip. is it possible to insert value thru url to DB?if that sum one share the idea if u dealt with?

Comment: i found the issue...can anyone tell how to write htacess if ajax values are inserted directly through url?